# how to fix my error with Interaction Manager in unity and leap motion?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, motion, leap-motion

I want to pick objects in Unity with leap motion. I think I do it right, but my object doesn't have any layer and when I create layers with names ...

```
1 - Interaction
2 - InteractionNoClip
3 - BrushHands
```

... the compiler gives me this error:

> Only interaction behaviours are allowed to collide with the brush layer.
>       Assertion failed. Value was Null
>       Expected: Value was not Null
>       Assets/LeapMotionModules/InteractionEngine/Scripts/InteractionBehaviours/
>
> ActivityManager.cs:212)
>       Leap.Unity.Interaction.ActivityManager:UpdateState(Frame) (at 
>       Assets/LeapMotionModules/InteractionEngine/Scripts/InteractionBehaviours/
>
> ActivityManager.cs:178)
>       Leap.Unity.Interaction.InteractionManager:simulateFrame(Frame) (at 
>       Assets/LeapMotionModules/InteractionEngine/Scripts/ 
>       InteractionManager.cs:616)
>       Leap.Unity.Interaction.InteractionManager:FixedUpdate() (at 
>       Assets/LeapMotionModules/InteractionEngine/Scripts/ 
>       InteractionManager.cs:545)

What should I do?

Comment: `What should i do?!` Show us your code.

Comment: there is no code.... i used "Interaction Engine" and "Unity Core Asset" based on this movie tutorial:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MM7oyMv2uL8&t=36s

Comment: FWIW you are using an old version of the Interaction Engine. You'll probably have better luck using the latest version and looking at the example scenes that come packaged with it.
https://github.com/leapmotion/UnityModules/wiki/Getting-Started-%28Interaction-Engine%29

Comment: that's right but i have to use old version of interaction package, because i'm using unity 5.5.0 and it doesn't support new version's of interaction packages!!!!